# How to round a value from an expression?? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, rounding

I got the following expression that I want it to be rounded by 2 decimal places:

```
Sub Round_Ex2()
  Dim Pitch_Limit_W As Double

        Pitch_Limit_W = (291 / 20.95)
        Round("Pitch_Limit_W",2)


End Sub
```

I get an error when trying to run because on the second line it says :" Expected =". I just want to round the decimal value from that expression up to 2 decimal places.

I tried changing the round function by putting some parentheses but still the same issue.

Comment: Pitch_Limit_W should not be in quotes in your round statement. Other than that, this sub does nothing. You aren't using the result in any way. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want a basic round up from the Pitch_Limit_W value which is the result of that expression. The equation works perfectly fine, but it's giving me a huge decimal.

Comment: Just remove the quotes. Variables don't have quotes around them, only string literals, and I doubt you are wanting to round the string `"Pitch_Limit_W"`.

Comment: Just removed it and I still get this: "Expected: ="

Comment: `Pitch_Limit_W  = Round(Pitch_Limit_W, 2)`. Note that `Round` uses bankers' rounding, which is not the same functionality as the Excel `ROUND` function.

Comment: When you say, "Just removed it and I still get this: "Expected: ="  can you post your new code? Also this code still does nothing (and neither does the current answer below). Are you posting all your code? Or are you trying to create a function (that returns a value)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Round_Ex2()

  Dim Pitch_Limit_W As Double
  Pitch_Limit_W = (291 / 20.95)
  Pitch_Limit_W_Rounded = Round(Pitch_Limit_W, 2)

End Sub
```

You have to assign the result to a variable.